# i want to know the overall time complexity for this code! below code sorts an array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, time-complexity

i used heap function to sort the array

```
import heapq


arr =[-74, 0, -4, 20, 7, 1, -4700, 74, 21, 71000, 87, 400, 9]
print ("The array: ", arr)
print("")
heapArray = arr
length = len(arr)
heapq.heapify(heapArray)
sortedArray = []

for each in (arr[:length]):
    sortedArray.append(heapq.heappop(heapArray))
    
arr = sortedArray
print ("The sorted array is:", arr)
```

this code sorts an array! i just want to know the overall complexity?

Comment: What did you find when you measured the execution time for different array sizes?

Answer (score 0):

Heap sort is a (n log n) algorithm.

Using `heapq.heapify()` will sort the array in linear time; or, O(n).

[Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) for reference.

Comment: but is this heap sort?? i mean.. i just used the heapify function only! nothing elsee.. is heapify function () itself performs in (n log n) time??